# How to set complex environment variables for linux in python?

Tags: python, linux, opencv, environment-variables

I know there have been similar questions on stackoverflow but I could not find anything like this one.

I'm trying to automatically set environment variables for openCV whenever I run python code.

Here is the code to temporarily set them up in linux:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
```

In linux, when I echo the PATH variable I get the following output:

```
/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin:/home/phil/.nvm/versions/node/v10.9.0/bin:/home/phil/bin:/home/phil/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

I use the following code in python:

```
os.environ['PATH'] = "/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}"
os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = "/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}"
```

But when I echo PATH in python, I get the exact same string for PATH.  What can I do to make python understand ${PATH:+:${PATH}} like linux does?

Comment: For `PATH`, at least, don't worry about whether `PATH` has a previous value. If it does not, you have bigger problems.

Answer (score 0):

`${PATH:+:${PATH}}` is `sh` syntax used in the `sh` programming/scripting language. Linux does not know or understand this syntax.

Since you are using Python, you should use Python syntax instead.

Here's the Bash documentation for this feature:

```
   ${parameter:+word}
          Use Alternate Value.  If parameter is null or unset,
          nothing is  substituted,  otherwise  the expansion of word
          is substituted.
```

So the direct translation into Python would be:

```
((":" + os.environ['PATH']) if os.environ['PATH'] else "")
```

There's nothing magic going on, in both language it's just shorthand for:

```
if os.environ['PATH']:
  # The path already had values, prepend ours with a colon:
  os.environ['PATH'] = "/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin" + ":" + os.environ['PATH']
else:
  # The path was empty, just set it to our directory without a colon
  os.environ['PATH'] = "/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin"
```

The purpose of this is to avoid a trailing colon if the path was not already set. If you instead did just:

```
os.environ['PATH'] = "/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin" + ":" + os.environ['PATH']
```

then the path could end up being just `/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin:` and the trailing colon can potentially cause problems by adding the current directory to the search path.

Answer (score 0):

bash `export` evaluates the result immidiately, like this:

```
giannis@local:~ > export TEST_VAR=$PATH
giannis@local:~ > echo $TEST_VAR
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

whereas it is imoportant to remember that in python, the native behaviour of `os.environ` is different to this. the `os.environ` in python behaves like a dictionary actually. So when you try this

`os.environ['PATH'] = "/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}"`

It is not going to evaluate as it would in native bash. If you want to achive the same behaviour in python, you should rather do this

in bash:

`export SomeVariable="I am constructed in bash and the path is ${PATH}"`

in python, you can build a variable like this

`os.environ['some_key'] = "Like so: {something}".format(something=os.environ.get('SomeVariable', "")`

so in your case you could achieve the same with something like this

`os.environ['PATH'] = "/somthing/:{path}".format(path=os.environ['PATH']`